# Is it worth deploying Spark on YARN if I have no other cluster software?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have a Spark cluster running in standalone mode. I am currently executing code on using Jupyter notebook calling pyspark. Is there a benefit to using YARN as the cluster manager, assuming that the machines are not doing anything else?

Would I get better performance using YARN? If so, why?

Many thanks,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say YES by considering these points.

**Why Run on YARN?**

Using YARN as Spark’s cluster manager confers a few benefits over Spark standalone:

1. You can take advantage of all the **features of YARN schedulers for categorizing, isolating, and prioritizing workloads**.
2. Any how Spark standalone mode also requires worker for slave activity which can not run non Spark applications, where as with YARN, this is isolated in containers, so adoption of another compute framework should be a code change instead of infra + code. So the cluster can be shared among different frameworks.
3. **YARN is the only cluster manager for Spark that supports security**. With
   YARN, Spark can run against Kerberized Hadoop clusters and uses
   secure authentication between its processes.
4. YARN allows you to dynamically share and centrally configure the same
   pool of cluster resources between all frameworks that run on YARN.
   You can throw your entire cluster at a MapReduce job, then use some
   of it on an Impala query and the rest on Spark application, without
   any changes in configuration.

I would say 1,2 and 3 are suitable for mentioned scenarios but not point 4 as we assumed no other frameworks are going to use the cluster.

[souce](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/apache-spark-resource-management-and-yarn-app-models/)